# Getting SSL to work with Apache/Passenger on OSX

Tags: apache, macos, ssl, passenger

I use apache/passenger on my development machine, but need to add SSL support (something which isn't exposed through the control panel).  I've done this before in production, but for some reason I can't seem to get it work on OSX.

The steps I've followed so far are from a default apache osx install:

1. Install passenger and passenger preference pane.
2. Add my rails app (this works)
3. Create my ca.key, server.crt and server.key as detailed [on the apple website](http://developer.apple.com/internet/serverside/modssl.html).

At this point I need to start editing the apache configs, so I added:

```
# Apache knows to listen on port 443 for ssl requests.
Listen 443
Listen 80
```

I thought I'd try editing the passenger pref pane generated config first to get everything working, when I add:

It starts off looking like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName myapp.local
  DocumentRoot "/Users/jonnii/programming/ruby/myapp/public"
  RailsEnv development
  <Directory "/Users/jonnii/programming/ruby/myapp/public">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I then *append* this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName myapp.local
  DocumentRoot "/Users/jonnii/programming/ruby/myapp/public"
  RailsEnv development
  <directory "/Users/jonnii/programming/ruby/myapp/public">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </directory>

  # SSL Configuration
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP
  SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StdEnvVars +StrictRequire

  #Self Signed certificates
  SSLCertificateFile /private/etc/apache2/ssl.key/server.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /private/etc/apache2/ssl.key/server.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /private/etc/apache2/ssl.key/ca.crt

  SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

</VirtualHost>
```

The files referenced all exist (I doubled checked that), but now when I restart my apache I can't even get to `myapp.local`.  However apache can still server the default page when I click on it in the sharing preference panel.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Apache doesn't support virtual hosts for SSL. You probably have another SSL virtual host entry somewhere, which is getting used instead. Remove that and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

The OS X distribution of Apache includes a sample config file for enabling SSL: see `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-ssl.conf`. Just ensure that config is valid for your needs, then find the following line in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`:

```
#Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```

and uncomment it by removing the octothorp.

Answer (score 2):

instead of defining two virtual hosts, just define one with the header:

```
<VirtualHost *:443 *:80>
```