# Getting SSL to work with Apache/Passenger on Mac OS with "Snow Leopard"

Tags: macos, ssl, apache2, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger

I have a Mac OS with "Snow Leopard" v10.6.5 and I am developing a Ruby on Rails 3 application using Passenger Preference Pane v 1.3.

To continue to develop my application I need a **SSL** support, but I have a similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439539).

The steps I've followed are from a default apache osx install:

1. Install Passenger and Passenger Preference Pane.
2. Add my Ruby on Rails application (that works)
3. Create my ca.key, server.crt and server.key as [detailed on the Apple website](http://web.archive.org/web/20100924015056/http://developer.apple.com/internet/serverside/modssl.html)...

... but during the third step I had to stop for the following reasons happened on editing the /private/etc/apache2/**httpd.conf** file (see the Apple website for more info):

1.
 `Port 80 should be changed to #Port 80.`

I have not found "Port 80", but I think this is not a problem because even if it is present in the code, it has been commented out.

2.
 `You will need to add the following just below where the Port directive was:`

```
< IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    Listen 443
    Listen 80
< /IfModule>
```

If I add these lines of code and restart apache2, my application no longer works.

3.
 `[...] The two lines should now look like this:`

```
LoadModule ssl_module libexec/httpd/libssl.so

AddModule mod_ssl.c
```

Since the code 'AddModule mod_ssl.c' does not exist (LoadModule is ready for use), I tried to add it and restart apache2, but my application no longer works.

4.
 `Now find the “ServerName” directive and make sure it has 127.0.0.1 for it’s entry.`

```
ServerName 127.0.0.1
```

I do not know if I have to enter it, since I use Passenger. However, in the file I found the line of code (already commented) '#ServerName www.example.com:80'.

Regarding the code for Passenger for the SSL certificates, I suppose that it must be the same as the [problem reported above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439539).

I think that this is due to the fact that the guide was written a long time ago. So, **what should I do to use SSL with apache2?**

Just to be clear, I also include the code related to Passenger Preference Pane...

.../private/etc/apache2/**httpd.conf**

```
   LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
   PassengerRoot /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2
   PassengerRuby /usr/local/bin/ruby

# Added by the Passenger preference pane
# Make sure to include the Passenger configuration (the LoadModule,
# PassengerRoot, and PassengerRuby directives) before this section.
<IfModule passenger_module>
  NameVirtualHost *:80
  <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName _default_
  </VirtualHost>
  Include /private/etc/apache2/passenger_pane_vhosts/*.conf
</IfModule>
```

.../private/etc/apache2/passenger_pane_vhosts/**subdomain.domain.com.vhost.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

  ServerName subdomain.domain.com
  DocumentRoot "/Users/<my_user_name>/Sites/subdomain/public"
  RackEnv development
  <Directory "/Users/<my_user_name>/Sites/subdomain/public">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

  # SSL Configuration
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP
  SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StdEnvVars +StrictRequire

  #Self Signed certificates
  SSLCertificateFile /private/etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /private/etc/apache2/ssl/server.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /private/etc/apache2/ssl/ca.crt

  SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: The document you're following on Apple's site is about 10 years old and targets Apache 1.3 as was then installed with Mac OS X. The instructions will not apply cleanly to the current Apache 2.2 installs. Try the Apache documentation instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just hit the same issue and this is what I did to get it working.

Follow your same steps to generate the keys (also further on it mentions removing the passphrase. I had to do this for things to work).

Next, I did the following to enable SSL on Apache:

In the "/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf" file on my Snow Leopard there was a line:

```
# Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-manual.conf
```

I just removed the # and saved the file.

Next edit the file (/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-manual.conf) and make sure

```
SSLCertificateFile
SSLCertificateKeyFile
```

point to the correct key files that you created.

Next there is an entry in the same file (/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-manual.conf) that begins:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
```

I had to comment out that file and everything after it (or you could just delete it) up to the

```
</VirtualHost>
```

entry. That entry conflicted with my site.

The Virtual host entry you had looks correct, but for completeness I will add mine here.

I just modified the original Vhost file that was created by Passenger PrefsPane for my site:

```
<VirtualHost *:443 *:80>
  ServerName mysite.local
  DocumentRoot "/Users/username/mysite/public"
  RackEnv development
  <Directory "/Users/username/mysite/public">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
  SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StdEnvVars +StrictRequire
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/sslkey/server.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/sslkey/server.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/sslkey/ca.crt
  SetEnvIf User-Agent &quot;.*MSIE.*&quot; nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
</VirtualHost>
```

Next restart Apache and you should be good to go. :-)

Comment: If you try to *verify the peer* for HTTPS connection in *localhost*, it will work using your self-signed certificates?

Comment: It should do, though as it is localhost testing I didn't worry too much about the security warning :-)